# How To Get @mdi/fonts To Display icon

Tags: css, angular, web, web-frontend, material-design-icons

I installed `@mdi/fonts` for an angular project. Everything works fine when I run `ng serve` or `ng build`, I get to see the icons displayed. But the icons becomes boxes when I run `ng build --prod`. I don't know why this is happening. How can I solve this. My project is an Angular 10 project.